# Client timeout on AWS Couchbase cluster after upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, couchbase

After we upgrade to Rails 3.2.8 with Ruby 1.9.3 (from 1.8.7), our Couchbase client could no longer access our AWS cluster (Couchbase 1.8 Community Edition).

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > c = Couchbase.new("http://ec2-184-169-237-63.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8091")
=> #<Couchbase::Bucket:0x007fe12d9e6c98 "http://ec2-184-169-237-63.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/default/" default_format=:document, default_flags=0x0, quiet=false, connected=true, timeout=2500000> 

1.9.3p194 :012 > c.get("hello")
Couchbase::Error::Timeout: failed to get value (key="hello", error=0x16)
    from (irb):12:in `get'
    from (irb):12
    from /Users/playmeshinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/playmeshinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/playmeshinc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

On the admin panel, we cannot even see any request reaching the server.

However, if we use the memcache protocol on port 11211, everything works well. If we try the same code and same call on our local couchbase cluster (OSX), things works just fine.

Any idea what might have happened? Is that because the Ruby Couchbase client is not compatible with AWS or Ruby 1.9.3?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I figured out, that's because moxi client on AWS would return internal ips which are not accessible to external machines, that's why it timed out when I was testing from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Gem is definitely compatible with EC2 and 1.9.3. What version of couchbase gem are you using? and what version of libcouchbase? Sounds like the culprit might be rvm or something else. I recommend trying to gem uninstall, and reinstall. Also make sure libcouchbase is up to date.

Comment: We are using couchbase server 1.8 on AWS.
We (two different engineers on two different boxes) tried client version 1.2.0.dp6, and then 1.1.1 and 1.1.3. They all failed to connect to the aws server.
1.1.1 and 1.1.3 gave us the following errors:
Couchbase::Error::Connect: failed to get value (key="aaa", error=0x17)

Comment: I started a server on http://ec2-50-18-227-192.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8091/pools/default/buckets/default, could you check if you can use couchbase to set/get some value? I can connect to the server, but the set/get would timeout.

Comment: Most likely you will run into timeout issues if you try to connect to couchbase server over the internet. It's designed for high performance and if it takes a long time to connect and do operations they will timeout. I recommend using an API in front that connects to Couchbase rather than direct connections from your laptop/desktop to remote ec2 machines.